# macro that inverts numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need some help figuring this out. I created a small script that changes a value in a cell into a positive if the number is negative and vice versa. For example if the value is 100 the script will change it to -100 or if it's -100 it changes to 100. I was able to make it work for one cell but now I would like to inplimented on a range of cells for example all cells from B33 to B50. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Sing_Change()

If Range("E9") > 0 Then
    Range("E9") = -(Range("E9"))
    Else
    Range("E9") = Abs(Range("E9"))
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: All you need is to negate the value, using `-Range(E9)`: this makes positive numbers negative and negative numbers positive, with no effect on zero.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What I'm stuck in is trying to create a loop with this script that will go down the column starting at B33 to B50.

Comment: What if the cell contains a numeric result out of a formula?

Comment: For a sign change just multiply by -1 ... minus 1... no need to check range or anything.

Comment: @AFH sorry - I saw the code and jumped, now realise you said the same...

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to create a new column, so that `C33:C50` are the negative of `B33:B50`. Create `C33` as `=-B33` (or `=-Range(B33)` - I have no idea what `Range()` does), copy this cell, select `C34:C50` and paste.

Comment: @Eric You need to reword your question if you really meant to ask about getting the code to loop down the column. Everyone seems to be talking about switch the number.

Comment: @CharlieRB let me rework the question because that's exactly what I'm look for that you stated.

Comment: @SolarMike - No problem: I often cross comments, and sometimes answers, with other contributors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very basic code to loop thru a specified range.

```
Sub test()

    Set myrange = Range("A1:A2") 'Set range here

    For Each cell In myrange
        'your code here e.g. cell.value = -cell.value or whatever
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the loop, you can use a single line with the `[]` brackets, which ask the macro to Evaluate what you want to do. As with all great powers, it comes with great responsibilities.

```
[B33:B50] = [-B33:B50]
```